# How to restart a supervised task that crashes

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

```
{:ok, tas} = Task.Supervisor.start_link(restart: :transient, max_restarts: 4)
a = 1
Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(tas, fn -> IO.puts "#{a}..." end)
Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(tas, fn ->
  IO.puts "Not Restarting :( "
  1 = 2
end)
a =  a + 1
Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(tas, fn -> IO.puts "#{a}.." end)
a =  a + 1
Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(tas, fn -> IO.puts "#{a}.." end)
```

The option `restart: :transient` does not seem to have any effect.

I've few tasks  `Task.async(fn(x) -> fetch_info(x) end` that make an http request to get multiple resources, and has timeout error. It would be nice to retry those failing tasks, instead of using `try`, `rescue`.

I think `async_nolink` is the closest I got without crashing the process. If there is no way using `Task`, do we have a simpler approach using `Supervisor` that starts multiple process which exists once their job is done and restart them if they fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to use `Task.Supervisor.start_child` instead of `Task.Supervisor.async_nolink` to have the children properly restarted:

```
{:ok, tas} = Task.Supervisor.start_link(restart: :transient, max_restarts: 4)

Task.Supervisor.start_child(tas, fn -> 1 = 2 end)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Tasks are the best bet for what you want. In the docs [Task Docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html) it is said that:

> This module defines a supervisor which can be used to dynamically supervise tasks. Behind the scenes, this module is implemented as a :simple_one_for_one supervisor where the workers are temporary (i.e. they are not restarted after they die).

and

> :restart - the restart strategy, may be :temporary (the default), :transient or :permanent. Check Supervisor.Spec for more info. Defaults to temporary as most tasks can’t be effectively restarted after a crash;

You should be looking into `GenServer` and building a pool of workers maybe [GenServer Intro](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html). The book Little Elixir and OTP Guide is pretty good for this, I've read about half of it and it provides a good foundation for OTP, distribution and Supervisors.

EDIT: I've just checked the book and couldn't find anything about restarting Tasks, just processes.